# NoSuchElement exception even when element appears in Inspect

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm running into an error trying to scrape data from a website with python and selenium.  The website has plenty of time to load, and I can see the element I want to grab via the webdriver browser's Inspect.  But find_element still fails.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait #waiting properly for things to load? [unused]
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By #Finding particular things
import time


sURL = 'https://theanalyst.com/eu/2023/07/fifa-womens-world-cup-stats-2023-opta/'

myChromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#myChromeOptions.add_argument("--headless") #Would prefer this to be headless later, but need the debugging visibility now.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = myChromeOptions)
driver.get(sURL)

time.sleep(100) #Wait a sufficiently long time that I see the data I want in the browser that opens. 
# At this point, if I Inspect inside the webdriver chrome browser, I see the data I'm looking for, namely a <div class="predictions-container">

element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "predictions-container") #Throws selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException
```

EDIT : Thanks Shawn.  This solved everything.  For anybody from the future, this is the corrected code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait #waiting properly for things to load
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # For waiting a proper amount of time for a specific thing.
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By # Finding particular things

sURL = 'https://theanalyst.com/eu/2023/07/fifa-womens-world-cup-stats-2023-opta/'

myChromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
myChromeOptions.add_argument("--headless") # This works with headless!
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = myChromeOptions)
driver.get(sURL)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, "iFrameResizer0")) #From Shawn's answer
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "predictions-container"))) #Smarter waiting than before
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "predictions-container") # This now sets element properly.
# Do Stuff with element here.  After the next switch_to, element will throw selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException
driver.switch_to.default_content() # Switch back out of the frame (to the main page), in case I need to do other stuff.  Again, from Shawn's answer.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desired element is wrapped within an IFRAME. See below:

[image]

Use the code below to switch into this FRAME first, then perform the other actions which you want to do:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.ID, "iFrameResizer0"))
```

Once you have performed actions within the IFRAME, you can use below code to come out if it:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```